# JavaScript algorithm to check for Palindrome by deleting at most one character - time complexity for this recursive approach

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

Here is the [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome-ii/) where you are given a string `s` and you can delete at most one character to judge whether or not this is a palindrome. For example,

```
Input: "abca"
Output: True
Explanation: You could delete the character 'c'.
```

So here is my solution using recursion

```js
var validPalindrome = function(s) {
    if(s.trim().length === 0) return true
    
    const isValidPalindrome = (start, end, skipped) => {
        if(skipped > 1) return false
        if(start >= end) return true
        if(s[start] === s[end]) return isValidPalindrome(start+1,end-1, skipped)
        else return isValidPalindrome(start, end - 1, skipped + 1) || isValidPalindrome(start + 1, end, skipped + 1)
    }
    
    return isValidPalindrome(0, s.length - 1, 0)
};
```

When there's a mismatch between the left character and the right character, you can skip one or the other, but you don't know which one.  Therefore, at this point, you simply need to explore both of these paths.

But I am having a hard time analyzing the time complexity for this type of recursion. I know that the iterative version of this solution should have an `O(n)` runtime. Not sure how I can approach analyzing the time complexity here.

Comment: Print a single character or save it to a file each time you enter the function. After some test, you will see if the number of characteres printed are N, >N or <N

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña I know I can do that but it is not a good answer if you get asked this during an interview.

Comment: You are looking for a way to understand whats the complexity... If you cant see it right away, then you should do some tests... Otherwise run it in pen and paper how many times it got executed in the best case scenario and the worst case... You will find that will get executed  ~N/2  but do it the way you like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of the recursive calls, start gets increased and/or end gets decreased. The recursion stops when start >= end. Therefore in the worst possible case when only start or end changes at each iteration, it will recurse end - start = n times.

As you already observed, the two recursive calls could be a problem, but as skipped gets increased, and recursion stops when skipped > 1, this path will only be taken once. As such we could rewrite the code into two functions, with the second one being:

```
     const isValidPalindromeTailRecursion = (start, end) => {
       if(start >= end) return true
       if(s[start] === s[end]) return isValidPalindrome(start+1,end-1, skipped)
       else return false;
    };
```

Now determining the time complexity of this version is easy as we only have tail recursion:

```
 T(1) = 1
 T(n) = T(n - 1) + 1 = n
```

Given that, we can take the original function and rewrite it:

```
     const isValidPalindrome = (start, end) => {     
       if(start >= end) return true
       if(s[start] === s[end]) return isValidPalindrome(start+1,end-1)
       else return isValidPalindromeTailRecursion(start, end - 1) || isValidPalindromeTailRecursion(start + 1, end)
    }
```

Now analyzing this one is way simpler, let's look at three cases:

1.) There is a valid palindrome:

`isValidPalindrome` recurses through the string, increasing start and decreasing end each step. Therefore there will be n / 2 recursive steps. In this case the time complexity is O(n).

2.) There is no palindrome, and only the m'th character is different:

`isValidPalindrome` recurses m times, till it find's the different character. From there on `isValidPalindromeTailRecursion` gets called twice, and recurses till the end (n - m steps). In total there are m + 2 * (n - m) steps, resulting in a time complexity of O(n).

3.) There is no palindrome, and multiple characters are different:

Just as in 2.) `isValidPalindrome` recurses m times till the first difference is found, then `isValidPalindromeTailRecursion` recurses twice, till the second difference is found, at that point the algorithm terminates. In total there are m + 2 * (m² - m) steps (where m² is the place of the second occurence). As m, m² < n, this also results in a time complexity of O(n).

As such, this algorithm is O(n) overall.

Comment: I think the intuition here is simpler and better to understand than the theoretical approach. Where the latter would be useful is if the max number of `skipped` characters was dynamic (another parameter to the function).

Comment: @Bergi true, actually thought I could solve that equation presenting a proper proof, however I failed :) I rewrote the answer using "intuition" ...